# C# UnitTest - Assert.AreEqual() does not call Equals if the argument is null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, equals

i recently stumbled upon a seemingly weird behavior that Google completely failed to explain.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

class TestClass
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    TestClass t = new TestClass ();
    Assert.AreEqual (t, null); // fails
    Assert.IsTrue (t.Equals (null)); // passes
}
```

I would expect this test to succeed. However, in Visual Studio 2008 / .NET 3.5 it fails. Is it intended to be like that or is it a bug?

Comment: Since the expected value in NUnit is always first, you're using AreEqual() backwards from convention.  I can't tell from the docs if it compares t against null, or null against t, so I would not call a test that relies on that distinction reliable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your TestClass violates the contract of [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx). `Assert.AreEqual` is relying on that contract, quite reasonably.

The docs state (in the list of requirements):

- x.Equals(a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)) returns false.

Comment: Then why does the last assert pass? Shouldn't t.Equals(null) return false and hense not be Assert.Istrue?

Comment: @borisCallens: The assert passes *because* the implementation is violating the contract. `t.Equals(null)` *should* be returning false, but you can see from the implementation that it's *actually* returning true, so the broken assertion passes.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming the framework would skip the actual implementation in case of Null and just return false.

Comment: @borisCallens: How coud it? You're making a virtual method call in the last line - there's no code making decisions *other* than which implementation to call between your line and the `Equals` method itself. If you'd called `object.Equals(t, null)` that would have been different.

Comment: Given the contract stated in your post, I thought that whatever.Equals(Null) could be optimized by the compiler. But your last reply is giving me the feeling I'm missing something.

Comment: @borisCallens: No, `whatever.Equals(null)` will make it through to your `Equals` method. However, `Assert.AreEqual` *is* null aware. That's the difference.

Comment: I see :) Thanks for the patient explanation. This is a good thing to know as I think everybody doing unit tests is bound to bump into this one at some point.

Answer (score 5):

When testing for nulls, do not use `Assert.AreEqual`.

You have to use `Assert.IsNull()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The first test fails. Test if "t" is null, which isn't, because you initialized the t with a new TestClass object.

The second test, passes, because t.Equals always returns true.

If one test fails, the whole TestMethod1 is marked as failed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's correct - you've initialised t to a new TestClass object, which isn't null, so the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, it is actually intended that `AreEqual(anythingButNull, null)` always return false?

(edit) The reason i wondered is because the test for null, as required by the contract of Equals, is not called when unittesting the class. So because AreEqual relies on the contract, it fails to check if my class also complies with the contract. So i guess i have to use the workaround of `Assert.IsFalse(blah.Equals(null))`.

Comment: Yes, because, simply spoken, (!null==null) has to return false.